# RemoveAttr JS on a button "disabled"

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, event-listener

I'm programming a little button to be enabled when I click on the first one.
This should be easy but I got a problem and it doesn't seem to work.
Would you give me a clue of what I'm missing?
Here is the code:

```html
<button id="valid-retrait">Try it</button>
<button id="relay" disabled>Yoyoyo</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  document.getElementById("valid-retrait").addEventListener("click", btn - enabled);

  function btn - enabled() {
    document.getElementById("relay").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three issues in your code. Firstly you cannot put JS code within a `<script>` block which has a `src` attribute. They need to be separated. However, as you don't use jQuery at all in the code you can remove the reference to it completely.

Secondly the hyphen character, `-`, is not valid in variable or function identifiers as it's used as the subtraction operator. You need to remove it, or use underscore, `_`, instead.

Lastly, there is no `element` keyword in JS. From the context you should be using `document` instead. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("valid-retrait").addEventListener("click", btnEnabled);

function btnEnabled() {
  document.getElementById("relay").removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```css
.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="democlass">Hello World</h1>

<p id="demo">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</p>

<button id="valid-retrait">Try it</button>
<button id="relay" disabled>Yoyoyo</button>
```

Just for clarity, here's the full HTML page structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .democlass {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="democlass">Hello World</h1>
  <p id="demo">Click the button to remove the class attribute from the h1 element.</p>

  <button id="valid-retrait">Try it</button>
  <button id="relay" disabled>Yoyoyo</button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("valid-retrait").addEventListener("click", btnEnabled);

    function btnEnabled() {
      document.getElementById("relay").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i wanted to thank you for your answer now i'm working as developper, thank you that you took the time to answer me when i was a real beginner.